# Typical Transistor Mismatch for 2N3904/2N3906

Tags: bjt, differential

Suppose you build a differential pair from mmbt3904(2N3904 surface mount equivalent) transistors with mmbt3906(2N3906 surface mount equivalent) for a current mirror. You also use transistors that are next to each other on the reel. What would be a typical mismatch value i.e. voltage offset?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhKjBW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you place the transistors in the order Q1, Q2, etc. from the reels, they should be quite closely matched(at least that is my experience). I was thinking that there shouldn't be that great of a mismatch in such a circuit. Or, more generally, what would be the mismatch, if you pick the transistors at random.

Comment: I lose you at "suppose you", as I can't imagine using discrete transistors where precision-matched pairs are called for.  Engineers design for worst case, so I'd always assume that one transistor will have minimum specs and the next will have maximum.

Comment: "*If you place the transistors in the order Q1, Q2, etc. from the reels, they should be quite closely matched*" - Not true. Consecutive transistors in a batch would be from different parts of the silicon wafer, i.e. small yet discernible differences in adjacent masks, plus small variations in packaging / bond-wire joints, or they might be from entirely different wafers i.e. more significant differences due to process variations, yet all within datasheet specifications. Proper design demands that one assume extreme cases at opposite ends of the ratings.

Comment: Shouldn't R1 go to the positive rail and the negative side of the 5V source go to ground?

Comment: Yeah, R1 was connected incorrectly. I edited it now. I was wondering what the offset would be. Surely it won't be more than a few 100mV.

Comment: Many of the classic matched pairs are no longer available, but there are some new (and cheap) matched pairs now on the market: the DMMT3904W (roughly a matched 3904) and DMMT5551 from Diodes Inc. and the PMP4501, PMP4201 and BCM847 from NXP may be possibilities. iirc. there are matched PNPs available too from these manufacturers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just measured \$V_{BE}\$ of 10 consecutive [C1815](http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/docget.jsp?pid=2SC1815&lang=en&type=datasheet) (jellybean Asian TO-92 NPN) transistors off an ammo pack tape (from a previous high-volume product design), and they were within a mV or so of each other. [image]

My guesstimate is that +/-1mV would definitely not be safe, but +/-20mV is probably a safe assumption, and more likely they'll be within +/-5mV ~ +/-10mV of each other. Your 100mV number is crazy safe, in my opinion, but actually there are **no** guaranteed numbers on the data sheet for \$V_{BE}\$ of an unsaturated [2N3904](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MMBT3904.pdf), just a typical figure of just over 600mV (at \$V_{CE}\$ of 5V and \$I_{C}\$ of 100uA), as shown on the graphs. There is also nothing I see on the data sheet that would let us calculate or interpolate such a number from other parameters.

The main reason for the negative sentiment here is that pretty much any 'safe' answer makes the type of circuit you've show (without emitter degeneration resistors) most likely somewhere between dubious and useless in a production design. Let's look at some real numbers, to get some feel for why this is so.

Take a simple dual-[2N3904](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MMBT3904.pdf) 100uA current mirror with no emitter degeneration and a 20mV (+/-10mV) offset voltage-- simulate that and you'll find that the mirrored current will be between 50uA and 225uA, depending on the polarity of the offset. That's not a crazy difference, but it's not the 10%-ish behavior you might expect of a basic current mirror.

I would say if you want to play with this kind of circuit on a breadboard, you'd probably get more-or-less useful, but not necessary *reproducible*, results (keep in mind that temperature differences from external or *self* heating will also affect the offset voltage by about -2.2mV/°C of temperature difference). You can always measure each one before you use it.

If you want to make a real design that will work over a guaranteed temperature range, and will work every time when it's built, you'll probably have use parts that both have guaranteed matching and have the transistors closely coupled thermally, or change your circuit design to one that is more insensitive to \$V_{BE}\$ matching.

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. I was simply curios. I do not intend to manufacture the above circuit in any way. It is useless anyway, because the output can't swing below the inverting input, i.e. collector voltage must be higher than base voltage, without the rest of the op-amp(common emitter stage and maybe an output stage).

Comment: I thought it was something like that. If you're still interested, check out the LM324 datasheet. It's simple enough that you could build an amplifier from discrete transistors on a breadboard (about 25-30 parts), and that design will allow the input to swing to ground, and the output almost that far.

Answer (score 1):

Bad question.  A *typical* spec is no use when designing a circuit.  What are you going to tell your customer, *"Gee, it typically works"*?

Yes, **maybe**, maybe even most of the time, two transistors adjacent on a real will have more closely matched specs than two randomly picked resistors of the same model.  But so what?  There is nothing responsible you can do with that information since you can't rely on it.  You have no idea what the process is of breaking apart a wafer of transistors, putting them into packages, and then putting those packages onto a tape.  Even if this is done in a regular stream, at some point the process will jump from the end of one row of dies to the start of the next, then to another whole different wafer.

So, look at the datasheet, find the min/max range of the parameter you want, and design the circuit assuming any part can be anywhere within that range.  That's called real engineering.  Wishful thinking and religious beliefs have no place in engineering.

One way to make a better matched current mirror is to put a resistor in series with each emitter.  That will lessen the effect of the two transistors having a different B-E voltage at the same current.  The cost is that the current mirror output can't go quite as close to the supply rail.  Everything is a tradeoff.